# how to store values in database at hierarchical view

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, hierarchical

In my project i need to create restaurant menu card,i want to insert values given below

```
-menus(like dinner,lunch,breakfast)
  .
   -menu_group(like soup,juice)
    .
    .
       -menu_item
              apple-juice...................... $10
              milk_shake_apple................. $15
       -menu_item

    -menu_group

-menu
```

which one is best custom field or taxonomy? or is there any plug in to use

Comment: You mean like **[this](http://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100816-191840.png)**?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a custom hierarchical taxonomy; call it 'menu'.

Top level terms (menus), have child terms (menu groups). Each child term has one or more posts (menu items) associated with it. Posts have custom fields (price) attached to them.

Note that you will need some custom code (a [category walker](http://scribu.net/wordpress/extending-the-category-walker.html)) to display the menu items for each menu group on the front-end.